# Why does the demon cat only eat eyeballs in Legend of the Demon Cat (妖猫传)?

Tags: character, legend-of-the-demon-cat

The demon cat in the Chinese movie [Legend of the Demon Cat](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legend_of_the_Demon_Cat) (妖猫传) only eats eyeballs.  From 25 minutes into the movie:

[image: 我只吃眼珠子]

> 我只吃眼珠子
>   I only eat eyeballs

In the movie, he eats both fish eyeballs and human eyeballs at various points.  However, I haven't figured out why he has this peculiar dietary restriction.

**Question**: Why does the demon cat only eat eyeballs?

It's possible that it's because it's creepy, but I feel there should be more to it.

Comment: Because they are tasty? ;)

Comment: Because he's a picky eater?